# f# parsing string to color

Tags: parsing, colors, f#

```
type circle = { X : int; Y : int; Diameter : int; Color : Color}
let mutable clickedCircle = { X = 0; Y = 0; Diameter = 0; Color = Color.White}

let txtBoxVal4 = System.Enum.Parse(typeof<Color>,txtBox2.Text)
clickedCircle <- {X = txtBoxVal2; Y = txtBoxVal3; Diameter = txtBoxVal1; Color = txtBoxVal4}
```

I am trying to parse a textbox.text into a color. From this code i get the error:

```
Error   1   This expression was expected to have type
Color    
but here has type
obj
```

Quite new to F# and not to sure about the syntax. The error comes at

```
"Color = txtBoxVal4"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Enum.Parse` returns an `obj` type that you need to cast to the enum type. You can do that using `:?>` or `downcast`. In your case the type is known so you can use `downcast`.

See the [Casting and Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220.aspx) docs for more.

```
clickedCircle <- {X = txtBoxVal2; Y = txtBoxVal3; Diameter = txtBoxVal1; Color = downcast txtBoxVal4}
```

Answer (score 1):

A wrapper function for `Enum.Parse` could make good use of the `enum` constraint and eliminate the need for unboxing at the call site.

```
module Enum =
  let parse<'T, 'U when 'T : enum<'U>> value = Enum.Parse(typeof<'T>, value) :?> 'T

let color = Enum.parse "Black"
```